# Unit testing a method return with org.specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I want to perform unit testing on the return values of a method nested under an object. Example:

```
package code.learn
import org.specs2.mutable._;
import com.learning.run.CMMDC;

class testing extends Specification {

    val t1 = Map(1 -> 6, 7 -> 12, 9 -> 13);
    "testing the results" in {
        foreach(t1) {
            case (key, value) =>
                CMMDC.compute(key, value) must_== value;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a `foreach` method](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#With+sequences) (or `foreachWhen` if you prefer to use a `PartialFunction`) in specs2 which tests several values for a given example:

```
"testing the results" in {
  foreach(t1) { kv => test.sampleMethod(kv._1) must_== someList(kv._2) }
}

// or
"testing the results" in {
  foreachWhen(t1) { case (k, v) => test.sampleMethod(k) must_== someList(v) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the map in as a [`Context`](https://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/DeclareSpecifications#Shared_contexts), which is a way to define fixtures. For example:

```
class testing extends Specification {

  var results: Map[Int, Int] = _
  val resultsMapOne = beforeContext(results = Map(1 -> 3, 5 -> 7))

  "sample method" definedAs resultsOne should {
    "with resultsMapOne" in {
      results foreach {
        case (key, value) => test.sampleMethod(key) must_== value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `test.sampleMethod` is straight from the question: the method for which we're trying to test input and the output. `"with resultsMapOne"` is just an arbitrary name for the test scenario, where `resultsMapOne` is a map with expected input/output as key->value

Comment: Looks like you found the answer - great!

Comment: A short note on this, it won't be possible to write an "in" block of code which type is `Unit`. I'll probably write a blog post explaining why before releasing 1.15 but in a few words the reason is that it is impossible to know if this `Unit` block is creating new nested examples or simply expectations. So in the future if you want to use a `foreach` inside an example you'll have to explicitly declare: `Result.unit { results foreach { ... } }`